# How to compare two lists in python iteratively?

Tags: python, loops

I have two lists: x_label and l

```
x_label = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
l = [60, 20, 10]
```

I want to print a bar - chart using the two lists which looks like this:

```
100|          
 90|          
 80|          
 70|          
 60| o        
 50| o        
 40| o        
 30| o        
 20| o  o     
 10| o  o  o  
  0| o  o  o
```

I must create a **single string** which contains this barchart. I have to create a for-loop which compares the lists x_label and l, and when an element  is the same between x_label and l, it adds the character 'o' from that point on vertically downwards to the string accordingly. This task must be done in an iterative manner.

I did the task in a different way non-iteratively. This code might help you in answering my question:

```
f = 60
c = 20
a = 10

x_label = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]

it = 0
ir = 0
ie = 0
bar_chart = ""
for i in x_label:
    bar_chart += (str(i) + "|" +"\n").rjust(5) 
    
    if i == f - it:
        it += 10
        bar_chart = bar_chart.rstrip("\n") 
        bar_chart += " " + "o" + "\n"
    if i == c - ir:
        ir += 10
        bar_chart = bar_chart.rstrip("\n") 
        bar_chart += "  " + "o" + "\n"
    if i == a - ie:
        ie += 10
        bar_chart = bar_chart.rstrip("\n") 
        bar_chart += "  " + "o" + "\n"


print(bar_chart)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem like this:

```
l=[60,20,10]
x_label = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
bar_chart = ""

for i in x_label:
    bar_chart += (str(i) + "|" +"\n").rjust(5)
    for e in l:
        if e>=i:
        
            bar_chart = bar_chart.rstrip("\n") 
            bar_chart += "  " + "o" + "\n"
print(bar_chart)
```

One loop that goes through your list x_label and the second checks wether the current value of x_label is smaller than the ones in l